# Run ActiveXObject COM component that creates dialogs under IIS in Asp.NET

Tags: asp.net, iis, com, activexobject

I have a ASP.NET MVC app, hosted on IIS on a dedicated server. At some point I need to create a com activex component. I use `Interaction.CreateObject` from `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction` for this.

The issue is that this activex component shows some dialogs when starting and waits until they are closed before actually registering as COM component.

I wrote some simple code that closes the windows via Windows API using `FindWindowEx` etc. and it works on a dev machine when hosted under VS, but it looks like on IIS these windows are never shown even in Windows API and ActiveX component just freezes waiting for dialogs to close that never exist.

I tried:

1. Using `Process.Start` and then `Interaction.GetObject` instead of `Interaction.CreateObject`
2. Setting AppPool in IIS to run from a real user identity
3. Setting Load User Profile to True in IIS
4. Using `https://github.com/mj1856/SimpleImpersonation` library to run the code as a user
5. I also looked in **dcomcnfg** (and this is my best bet on what I need to do). I thought I need to find my COM component there, and set Identity to specific user - but for some reason the ActiveX COM component I'm running does not exist there. I see "cannot register COM component" in Event Viewer if the component run crashes by timeout (because it waits for dialogs before registering as COM), - so I know `AppID`, but it does not exist in the list in `dcomcnfg`. Maybe because the ActiveX is `exe`, not `ocx`?

I know IIS is not supposed to run anything with windows, and it of course cannot show them, but I was at least expecting to see them with Windows API and being able to close them, especially given that the component waits for them to be closed, so they exist somewhere. I think I'm missing some clever setup on the server.

Comment: If there strictly nothing interactive on the server, then you may never be able to do this. Looks like your ActiveX needs a shell somehow, a Remote Desktop for example is ok, or contact your vendor. Maybe they don't support/licence server (non interactive) support.

Comment: It's fairly likely that the windows are being created on a separate [window station or desktop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681928(v=vs.85).aspx), and so are not enumerable from the interactive window station.   Services in particular are allocated separate desktops.